# Android studio Debug console closed

Tags: android-studio

I accidentally closed the debug console (I clicked on (x) close button on the debug console). I cant find how I can reopen it again.
I search every where in android studio but no success

Finally I found it. 
[Click On Restore layout as in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YmGm.png)

Answer (score 0):

There's a restore console view on Android Studio 3.5

[image]